# how to remove doube square brackets in json array - nodejs

Tags: node.js

Function 1 return array

```
var arra = [
   { TableTitel: 'Sockel', TableValue: 'AM4 (PGA)' },
   { TableTitel: 'Codename', TableValue: 'Matisse' },
   { TableTitel: 'iGPU', TableValue: 'N/​A' }
];
```

Json file:

```
var maindata = {
  podTitel: "AMD Ryzen 7 3700X, 8x 3.60GHz, boxed (100-100000071BOX)",
  podURL:
    "https://xml/amd-ryzen-7",
  podDesc:
    "Sockel: AM4 (PGA)",
  podStars: "4.9 von 5",
};
```

I want to create details array in Json maindata and put arra in details.

```
maindata.details = [];
maindata.details.push(arra);
```

Result is 
console.log(maindata);

```
{
  podTitel: 'AMD Ryzen 7 3700X, 8x 3.60GHz, boxed (100-100000071BOX)',
  podURL: 'https://xml/amd-ryzen-7',
  podDesc: 'Sockel: AM4 (PGA)',
  podStars: '4.9 von 5',
  details: [
    [
      { TableTitel: 'Sockel', TableValue: 'AM4 (PGA)' },
      { TableTitel: 'Codename', TableValue: 'Matisse' },
      { TableTitel: 'iGPU', TableValue: 'N/​A' }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Problem is: arra is array and details is also array, and details has after push() two square brackets.
what is the best way to remove double square brackets.

This should be the result

```
 {
      podTitel: 'AMD Ryzen 7 3700X, 8x 3.60GHz, boxed (100-100000071BOX)',
      podURL: 'https://xml/amd-ryzen-7',
      podDesc: 'Sockel: AM4 (PGA)',
      podStars: '4.9 von 5',
      details: [

          { TableTitel: 'Sockel', TableValue: 'AM4 (PGA)' },
          { TableTitel: 'Codename', TableValue: 'Matisse' },
          { TableTitel: 'iGPU', TableValue: 'N/​A' }

      ]
    }
```

tnx a lot

Comment: Either `maindata.details = arra;` or `maindata.details.push( ... arra);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
maindata.detail = [...arra];
```

**DEMO**

```js
var arra = [{
    TableTitel: 'Sockel',
    TableValue: 'AM4 (PGA)'
  },
  {
    TableTitel: 'Codename',
    TableValue: 'Matisse'
  },
  {
    TableTitel: 'iGPU',
    TableValue: 'N/​A'
  }
];


var maindata = {
  podTitel: "AMD Ryzen 7 3700X, 8x 3.60GHz, boxed (100-100000071BOX)",
  podURL: "https://xml/amd-ryzen-7",
  podDesc: "Sockel: AM4 (PGA)",
  podStars: "4.9 von 5",
};

maindata.detail = [...arra]; 

console.log(maindata);
```